# Is this a sensible object oriented design?

Tags: oop

```
---------------------
| AbstractPersister |
---------------------
         ^
        / \
        ---
         |
------------------
| OrderPersister |
------------------
         ^
        / \
        ---
         |
    ---------     ---------
    | Offer |<>---| Item  |
    ---------     ---------
```

The above is ascii art for a UML class diagram.  I have a domain class called "offer" which contains items.  E.g. an offer for a trip which costs 500 bucks and contains a bus ticket, a nights stay at a motel and a show.

When the customer checks out of the store, the offer is persisted to the database as an order containing order items.

Would it make sense in a pure object oriented design to make the offer inherit from an `OrderPersister`?  The `OrderPersister` can get a connection to the database using its super class, the `AbstractPersister`.  I want to add a method to `OrderPersister` called `Book`, which will create the order and its items in the database.

If this is a bad design, what alternatives are there?  I want this to be as object oriented as possible please.

Comment: Do you expect objective answers to this question?

Comment: Absolutely, don't you?  I appreciate design is subjective, but this is a serious question for which I am hoping to get some serious answers from people with experience.

Comment: There are three people who think this question is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Should I ask the last line of the question differently.  For example: Does inheriting from an OrderPersister break encapsulation, since Orders data is not offer data?  My problem is, I don't know what other objective questions to ask yet, since I need help...

Comment: @JanDvorak: how do you know its three people? I can only see the "-1"

Comment: I mean the three close votes that you _don't_ see.

Comment: OK, please advise on how to rephrase the question so that I don't get it closed, based on my previous comment.

Comment: It's still at 3, so I don't think this'll get closed.

Comment: If you don't have luck here, you can try in programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming concepts, and should be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before extending a class, you should ask this question: is a?

Is an Offer an OrderPersister? I say it's not.

You should take a look at the Data Mapper pattern. It will let you use domain objects that know nothing about persistence, and still be able to persist them.

Comment: Perfect - its exactly the type of objective answer I am looking for, thanks.